# Is it true that $g_n \circ f$ converges uniformly to $g \circ f$ on $[c,d]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_n$ are continuous functions converging uniformly to $f$ on the compact interval $[a,b]$ and $g_n$ is a sequence of functions converging uniformly to $g$ on $[a,b]$. Suppose further that $f: [c,d] \to [a,b]$ is a  continuous function.  Is it true that $g_n \circ f$ converges uniformly to $g \circ f$ on $[c,d]$?

I tried finding a counter example but it all involves the sequence being on $\mathbb{R}$. So, I am assuming that it is true and I do not know how to start proving it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $|g_n(f(x)) - g(f(x))| \leq \sup_x |g_n(x) - g(x)|.$ So yes. Did you mean $g_n \circ f_n$?

Comment: Thank you! I thought so too but it is just $g_n \circ f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_n$'s are converging uniformly to $f$, it is unnecessary to say that $f$ is continuous because it follows from a well-known theorem about uniform convergence. Basically, what you need is that uniform convergence restricted to a subset of the domain remains uniform.

Anyway, all you need to do is to write down the definitions. We know that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$. Therefore, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall n \geq M: \sup_{x\in [a,b]}|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$$

Particularly, $f[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$. Therefore, using the properties of supremum, namely $A\subseteq B \implies \sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$, we have

$$\forall n \geq M:\sup_{x\in [c,d]}|g_n\circ f(x)-g\circ f(x)| = \sup_{y\in f[a,b]}|g_n(y)-g(y)| \leq  \sup_{y \in [a,b]}|g_n(y)-g(y)|<\epsilon$$

Hence, $g_n\circ f \to g\circ f$ uniformly on $[c,d]$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Pika_2018 You're welcome. I'm glad that it helped.